# Fabric 3.6.1 + Text Object Selection issue using fabric.curvedText.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am applying normal text to curved text using fabric.curvedText.js.

So when i apply curved text then curved text is not fit in selection box

Here i am sharing error image.
https://prnt.sc/st09cc

We have using with Fabric 3.6.1 and fabric.curvedText.js here is the link

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js

https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or a working snippet?

Comment: @melchiar, here is fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/dev_vsl/7h2ecgw3

Comment: I don't believe this library officially supports Fabric v2+ yet, but it looks like you've got it close to working. The issue looks like it's related to the origin. Try setting the `originX` and `originY` to `center`

Comment: @melchiar, thanks, i have set `originX` and `originY` to `center` it's work for me :)

Comment: No worries. Just a suggestion since you seem to be making progress porting this plugin to the latest version, perhaps consider doing a PR to the project. I'm sure a lot of people would be grateful for the v2+ support.

Comment: Sure, i will :)